# Oracle Cloud Infrastructure. "No Active State" tenancy when creating autonomous database

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am new in OCI and I created my account in Oracle Cloud Free Tier.

I want to create an autonomous database, but I always get this error:

> Operation failed because the OCI tenancy with OCID ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaav6vqssmwmak4toidqdnvwtj6tk2urynptsevcwikmaqmar3ebk4a is not in the Active state.

[image]

When I check at my tenancy details, it appears as `Active`:

[image]

Can you help me to create my autonomous database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From screenshot account is active, however as CSI number is blank wanted to check if this is a new account created today ?

If Yes ,possibly account might not have fully-provisioned .Please contact Oracle cloud support via chat ,added screenshot for your reference.

Hope this helps . Incase if it is old account ,Please ignore my response.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, yes my account was created today. In fact, I received an email saying "We’re still setting up billing and a few other details, but you can go ahead and get started now. ". Im not sure if I have to wait for a while....

Comment: Yes Rahul. It was exactly what you said. I talk to support team. They told me, the provisioning was stucked. Thanks!!